# How to find a specific pattern in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I want to find a pattern `'@s241'` in a file, which is easy using:

```
grep '@s241' file
```

or

```
awk '/@s241/' file
```

But the problem is that the file contains patterns such as @s2470 or @s2478

How could I specify the exact pattern is @s247 with no extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-w` in grep.

```
grep -w '@s247' file
```

or

```
grep -P '(^|\s)@s247(\s|$)' file
```

or

```
awk '/(^| )@s247( |$)/'
```